# Azure 500 IOPS equivalent HD speed?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtualization

In azure, each Virtual Machine can have a certain number of drives attached each with a maximum speed of 500 IOPS. See [VM specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx)

I am configuring a SQL server and trying to gauge what the equivalent drive speed would be in traditional hard drives sense for sizing a striped set?

Would a 500 IOPS VHD be the equivalent of:

1. SATA II
2. SCSI 10K
3. SCSI 15K
4. SSD

I understand that this is not going to be accurate, but it could prove useful as a simple guide for migration from traditional HDD setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of limits that impact VHDs - 500 IOPS, 60 MB/s - and the actual performance depends somewhat critically on the specific workload. There are a number of SQL Server on Azure performance whitepapers which you may find helpful:

Performance [Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn248436.aspx) for SQL Server in Azure Virtual Machines

Azure SQL Database and SQL Server -- [Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj879332.aspx) and Scalability Compared and Contrasted

The following may also be of interest since it discusses how to use Azure Blob Storage directly in SQL Server 2014:

SQL Server 2014 and Azure Blob [storage integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/igorpag/archive/2014/06/22/update-new-white-paper-on-sql-server-2014-and-azure-blob-storage-integration.aspx)

Comment: The MS performance guidelines for SQL Server in Azure VM are an excellent read